# New Google policy - app access for phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play

> If parts of your app are restricted based on login credentials,
> memberships, location, or other forms of authentication, we need you to
> provide instructions on how to access them. This helps us review your
> app.
>
> If you don't provide this information, we'll assume that all
> functionality in your app is available without special access.
>
> As a general reminder, if we're unable to review your app for
> compliance (for example, because part of your app is behind a login
> wall but we don't have working login credentials), your app maybe
> blocked from releasing new updates or removed from Google Play.

I have Firebase phone authentication, how can I give a test account to Google review team? especially if the device needs to receive an SMS confirmation code.

The app requires authentication only for publishing post, every user can enter the app without authentication.

Link to policy:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455#app_access

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fictional phone numbers for [testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers).

You can follow the steps provided to setup fictional phone numbers and use these for testing.

There are some requirements to be met by these fictional phone numbers, like it should not match a real phone number, so follow those guidelines.